# Programmatically stop a vertical scroll?

Tags: android, scroll, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am developing a voice-controlled Android app and can successfully scroll up and down vertically using voice commands. I now wish to stop a vertical scroll at any moment, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Couldn't you just set the position to the current position?

Comment: How would I do that ? @brandall

Comment: Basically I am scrolling up or down based on voice inputs. I want to add an extra input which stops the scrolling wherever it is on the page.